# Debian: escape spaces in APT pin

Tags: debian, apt, apt-cache

I'm running Debian Wheezy on a Raspberry Pi and want to have both the Raspbian repo at `http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/` (for the OS) and the RPi Foundation repo at `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` (for the kernel and the firmware).

The problem is that the Foundation repo ships a newer version of `libpixman-1-0`, which breaks VLC build - so I want to use APT pinning to pin every package from the Foundation repo except `raspberrypi-bootloader`,`rpi-update` and `raspi-config`. In `apt-cache policy libpixman-1-0`, the output is as follows:

```
libpixman-1-0:
  Installed: 0.32.6-3
  Candidate: 0.33.1+git20140627-c37ff5-rpi1rpi1
  Version table:
     0.33.1+git20140627-c37ff5-rpi1rpi1 0
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
 *** 0.32.6-3 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output from `apt-cache policy` is (truncated):

```
 500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
     origin archive.raspberrypi.org
 500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing/main armhf Packages
     release o=Raspbian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Raspbian,c=main
     origin mirrordirector.raspbian.org
```

In theory, this block in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/01-rpi` should disable all except the three mentioned packages:

```
Package: *
Pin: o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
Pin-Priority: -1
Package: raspberrypi-bootloader
Pin: o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
Pin-Priority: 999
Package: raspi-config
Pin: o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
Pin-Priority: 999
Package: rpi-update
Pin: o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
Pin-Priority: 999
```

The problem is that this does not work due to the spaces in the pin name - `apt-cache policy` drops a warning:

```
W: Did not understand pin type o=Raspberry
```

How do I escape this space? I already tried wrapping it in single and double quotes as well as prepending a backslash, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a incorrectly formed pin.

```
Pin: o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
```

Try this instead.

```
Pin: release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,n=wheezy,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
```